# a problem about proving a harmonic function to be a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D\subseteq \Bbb C$ be a simply connected domain ,and let $f$ be a non-vanishing complex-valued harmonic function in $D$. Prove that if there is a branch of $\log f(x)$ which is also harmonic ,then either $f(x)$ or its complex conjugate $\bar{f}\left(x\right)$ is holomorphic on $D$.

I don't know how to make connection between $\log f(x)$ and $f(x)$.I'm not very sure which theorems I've learned concerning harmonic functions would be useful.Additionally all the harmonic functions I encountered before are all real-valued.

Comment: Do you mean $D\subset\mathbb C$?

Comment: $D$ is a unit disk in $C$